# Why arent strings (and likewise colors) defined in the android namespace?

Tags: android, xml-namespaces

I have a newbie android question:

Why arent strings and other resources like colors (defined in res/values directory) defined in android namespace by assigning the attribute 
xmlns:android="http://schemas......" to the  tag?

Comment: I think they dont have time to make it too developer friendly since android is open-source and you have to dealt with such things by yourself in open-source

Comment: @user829736: Your question makes no sense. You may wish try again.

Comment: @Saurabh: I'm sorry but open-source doesn't necessarily mean non developer friendly. I've found Linux & Open Office much better to use than Windows & MS Office. I think there is a misconception that open-source => dedicated, selfless programmers burning mid-night oil to write hobby code & sharing it with the world. Not quite so. Google is & will continue making a lot of money off Android & hence, has been improving & will keep improving it. Like any new platform, Android has had its teething troubles, but its a pretty decent platform to work on :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a "why" about it, but I imagine the best answer is that these XML files are so simple that a schema adds little value. On the one hand it would help editors find errors automatically; on the other hand it's a little more work for developers and the Android maintainers.